# Word for people formally flanking a path

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for the formation of people flanking a path as part of a formal occasion?  It is usually full of military men in formal uniform.  I believe it happens after some ceremonies where men in uniform hold out weapons above the heads of people walking through.
e.g. "The procession moved quickly down the middle of the X."

Comment: specific to weddings - [saber arch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saber_arch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**guard of honor**

> noun
>
> 1. a group of soldiers who line the path of and present arms as a sign of respect to a person being honoured as they pass.
> 2. any group of selected people who perform a similar ceremonial function.
>
> Also, guard of honor, honour guard, honor guard.

See [Macquarie Dictionary Online](https://www.macquariedictionary.com.au/features/word/search/?word=guard%20of%20honour&search_word_type=Both)

And from [the Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/guard_of_honour):

> guard of honour
>
> PHRASE
>
> A group of soldiers detailed to ceremonially welcome an important visitor.
>
> Example sentences
>
> > *‘A few yards away, their heads bowed, with rifles pointing towards the ground, stood their comrades, a guard of honour.’*
> >
> > ‘The President was having lunch today with the Queen at Buckingham Palace after reviewing a guard of honour in the Palace quadrangle.’